# How to set PulseAudio sinks in groups?

Tags: pulseaudio

I would like to setup some sort of virtual sink or source group that will allow me to change a sink for several active input streams. Thus far, I have been using the following script to set all input streams to the default source:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
pacmd set-default-sink "$1"
pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep index | while read input
do
  pacmd move-sink-input "${input##* }" "$1"
done
```

Or to only move inputs to the last default sink:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
pacmd list-sinks |
grep -e "* index:" |
tr -dc "[:digit:]\n" |
{
  read old_sink
  pacmd set-default-sink "$1"
  pacmd list-sink-inputs  |
  grep -e "index:" -e "sink:" |
  grep -B 1 -e "sink: $old_sink" |
  grep -e "index:" |
  tr -dc "[:digit:]\n" |
  while read i
  do
    pacmd move-sink-input "$i" "$1"
  done
}
```

However, this does not suit my needs. Similar solutions assume that I want all input streams pointing to one target sink to move to another. I would like a solution that provides the following behavior:

```
# previous state
sourceA -> (virtualSink -> sinkA)
sourceB -> (virtualSink -> sinkA)
sourceC -> sinkA

$ set-sink (virtualSink -> sinkB)
sourceA -> (virtualSink -> sinkB)
sourceB -> (virtualSink -> sinkB)
sourceC -> sinkA
```

Ideally, `set-sink` would move all active input streams to the new sink, but iterating over the input streams pointing to `virtualSink` would be perfectly acceptable.